# React Native with Quill.js Editor Cursor Issue on Android, works fine on iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview, quill

I'm using React Native with Quill.js for text editing, and I'm encountering a specific issue with cursor behavior in the Android environment. When I paste content into the Quill.js editor on Android, the cursor does not display at the end of the pasted text. The problem does not occur on iOS devices.

Here are some key points:

- I'm using the Quill.js editor within a React Native app, and the issue only appears on Android devices.
- The Quill editor is implemented in a WebView within my Android app.
- I've ensured that I'm using the latest version of Quill, as well as the Android WebView component.
- I've checked for known issues and conducted tests on different Android versions, but the problem persists.

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this Android-specific issue and make the Quill.js editor behave consistently with iOS within my React Native project.
Thank you.